# split the sentence with respect to my scanned list words

Tags: r

I have a list of word that like below:

```
a <-c ("swipe","swiped", "electric", "blower", "shock", "wipe", "capacitor", "resistor")
```

I have got a sentence like that needs to be split:

```
b <- c("swipedshockelectricwipeblower")
```

I need the below output:

```
c <- ("swiped", "shock", "electric", "wipe", "blower")
```

and I do not need the output like below (since both swiped and swipe are there in my list of words)

```
c_wrong <- ("swipe", "d", "shock", "electric", "wipe", "blower")
```

Comment: Try `stringr` `unique(unlist(str_extract_all(b, a)))`  In your 'a', there are `swipe` and `swiped`.  It can extract both `swipe` and `swiped`.  Are you looking for the longest mastch

Comment: i did not get. I tried with unique(unlist(str_extract_all(b, a)))

Comment: I only need swiped and not swipe. Because in case if it extracts swipe, then only d is left over that does not have any meaning

Comment: You appear to want to select the longest word matches only.  However, where you said:

`I need the below output:
 c <- ("swiped", "shock", "electric", "wipe", "blower")`

I believe you have to exclude "wipe" on the same basis that you excluded "swipe" i.e because both "wipe" and "swipe" are shorter substrings of "swiped".  If so, please edit that line in your question yourself.  (My suggested edit to fix that was rejected.)